# How to add a rows for mutli totals and Grand Total

Tags: python-3.x

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzpDF.png)

Here is the Data i have.
Could help me to add a additional rows for total of Project Close Date in quarter , Total of each of Salesperson , total of each of project name & Grand Total ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OGs3.png)

Expected the output like this format

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow! Please edit your question that it contains data we can copy and test with. Also we expect you to try and show us what you have tried, because people in this forum are here to help you with code problems.

You could read your excel file into a pandas dataframe and use `groupby` function to group user data and use `sum` to calculate sum.